# Fragment transaction on a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, fragment

I'm trying to make a fragment transaction that requires some time to run on a thread, so that the UI doesn't stop and I can show something like a progress bar.
I already tried this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(); //This fragment requires some time to show
                String fragmentTag = "fragmentTag";
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, fragmentTag);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }).start();
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Better to use this new thread within fragment methods itself and let the transaction happen on main thread.

If you are performing some calculations(non UI) within fragment then put that block into a new thread let.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(); //This fragment requires some time to show
            String fragmentTag = "fragmentTag";
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, fragmentTag);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
        }
    }).start();
```